# Why is Kibana unable to create index pattern? (ELBK)

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am trying to setup filebeats to log from our spring applications to logstash.. I found a good tutorial that has exactly what I need to test locally..

http://www.andrew-programming.com/2018/09/18/integrate-springboot-application-with-elk-and-filebeat/

But when I go to create an index pattern I get a message saying -

Couldn't find any Elasticsearch data
You'll need to index some data into Elasticsearch before you can create an index pattern.

Here is my logstash config file

```
# Sample Logstash configuration for creating a simple
# Beats -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch pipeline.

input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    #user => "elastic"
    #password => "changeme"
  }
}
```

filebeats.yml file

```
#=========================== Filebeat inputs =============================
filebeat.inputs:

- type: log

  # Change to true to enable this input configuration.
  enabled: false

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    - /opt/test.log

#============================= Filebeat modules ===============================

filebeat.config.modules:
  # Glob pattern for configuration loading
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

  # Set to true to enable config reloading
  reload.enabled: false

#==================== Elasticsearch template setting ==========================

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 3

#============================== Kibana =====================================

# Starting with Beats version 6.0.0, the dashboards are loaded via the Kibana API.
# This requires a Kibana endpoint configuration.
setup.kibana:

#-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
#output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

#================================ Processors =====================================

# Configure processors to enhance or manipulate events generated by the beat.

processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
```

Comment: is logstash setup to communicate with ES server? Download the elastic-search head plugin in chrome and check if the index is created in ES server or not. Kibana can only discover the index when the ES has that index in it

Comment: I can't find that plugin in extensions, any other way i can check?

Comment: This is the plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/elasticsearch-head/ffmkiejjmecolpfloofpjologoblkegm?hl=en . It basically consumes the elastic search server api

Comment: Got the plugin but all i can see is 
kibana_1,
kibana_2, and 
tasks

Comment: Which means that kibana is consuming the ES url but your logstash is not communicating with the ES server. You have to configure that part. After that you'll be able to see an index in the ES-head. Once that is done, you will have to add the index in kibana

Comment: I am just using the logstash sample config file and running elastic-search locally so it should be configured?

Comment: Yes, something like `hosts => ["localhost:9200"]` where localhost can be the api/url/ip of the es server. Can you edit your post with the logstash config file and the elastic search api?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190094/discussion-between-krishna-and-mick-ogorman).